# google-code-prettify doesn't work for matlab code

Tags: matlab, google-code-prettify

I am using the google-code-prettify package to highlight my matlab code, however the highlight does not look like matlab-style coloring. My minimal working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="prettify/prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="prettify/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="prettify/run_prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <pre class="prettyprint lang-matlab">
      <code>
      i=1;
      if i==2
         i=1;
      end
      while(1)
         a=5;
      end
      %test comment
      </code>
      </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, for instance, `%test comment` is not highlighted in green, however SOME lines are highlighted, e.g. the while-loop. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both `prettify.js` or `prettify.css` when you use `run_prettify.js`.  Just add `?lang=matlab` to the `run_prettify.js` URL and it will load all the JS and CSS you need.

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted says

> You can load the JavaScript? and CSS for prettify via one URL
>
> ...
>
> For example
>
> ```
> <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=css&skin=sunburst"></script>
> ```
>
> specifies the `lang` parameter to also load the CSS language extension and the skin parameter to load the *sunburst* skin.

So your `<head>` should look like

```
<head>
   <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=matlab" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the matlab language handler:

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/lang-matlab.js"></script>
```

Comment: @noam: Where did you put it?

Comment: @noam: Try putting it between the two script tags.

Comment: did you try the example I posted above, with your addition? Does it work for you? I really don't know what's wrong...

Comment: @noam: You might have to include the matlab stylesheet as well: https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: Just add `?lang=matlab` to the `run_prettify.js` URL per https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted